# What is the better solution to get the Entity I want in a biderectional OneToMany relation?

Tags: symfony, twig, repository, entity

I have one entity Article and an other entity Image with a bidrectional relation OneToMany and ManyToOne :

```
class Article
{
   /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Image",  mappedBy="article")
   */
    private $images;
}

class Image
{
   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Article", inversedBy="images")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
   */
    private $article;
}
```

In my controller I use @paramconverter to get the article I want :

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/{slug}", name="article")
 * @ParamConverter("article", class="AppBundle:Article")
 */
public function articleAction(Article $article)
{
    return $this->render('default/article.html.twig', array(
        'article' => $article,
    ));
}
```

Now my problem is that I want to identify the ONLY image with the attributes "main = true" in all the "article.images" I have.

**What is the best solution?**

In my wiew I can do somehting like this but it's not the best I think :

```
 {% for image in article.images %}
   {% if image.main %}
       <img src="{{ asset( image.src ) }}" alt="{{ image.alt    }}" title="{{ image.title }}">
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

I'd like to use something like :

```
 {{ article.mainImg }}
```

**How can I achieve this please? And is this the best solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine provides a collection filter mechanism you could use to get the "main image":

```
public function articleAction(Article $article)
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("main", true))
        ->setMaxResults(1);

    $mainImg = $article->getImages()->matching($criteria)->first();
    return $this->render('default/article.html.twig', array(
        'article' => $article,
        'mainImg' => $mainImg
    ));
}
```

More information on filtering doctrine collections: [Filtering collections](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)

I did not test the code myself, but it should convey the idea of how it can be done.

Comment: Perfect thank you ! I'm still a Symfony beginner and didn't know a lot about this kind of stuff, I will try to improve myself in this domain :) Thanks again ;)